# How to enable gzip compression of Angular 6 asp.net core 2.1 which is hosted in Azure App services

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1

How do I enable gzip compression for Angular 6 asp .net core 2.1 which is hosted in Azure App services. Do I have to handle it in the code or is it a setting in Azure app services.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to enable gzip compression for your app hosted in Azure App Services.

1. Follow the IIS offical document [HTTP Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/)  to configure the `web.config` file to enable it like the [configuration sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpcompression/#configuration-sample) as below.

> ```
> <configuration>
>     <system.webServer>
>         <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
>             <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
>             <dynamicTypes>
>                 <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
>                 <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
>                 <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
>                 <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
>             </dynamicTypes>
>             <staticTypes>
>                 <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
>                 <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
>                 <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
>                 <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
>             </staticTypes>
>         </httpCompression>
>     </system.webServer>
> </configuration>
> ```

2. Install a site extension named [IIS.Compression Site Extension](https://github.com/shibayan/IIS.Compression.SiteExtension) on Azure portal or Kudu Site extensions, as the figures below.

Fig 1. Move to `Extension` tab and click `Add` on Azure portal

[image]

Fig 2. Choose extension on Azure portal

[image]

Fig 3. Installation on Kudu Site extensions

[image]

Comment: @kumar Does it work for you? If it works, could you mark the answer?